# Read Excel file in R with multiple date format

Tags: r, excel, date-format

I'm trying to read an Excel file in R, with two columns containing dates. Now here is my problem, when I view my data file in R, most of the dates are in the good format, but some were transformed into number that don't make sense at all. I joined images to show the different outputs from R/Excel.

(Only pay attention to the columns "ArrivalDate" and ActlFlightDate")

[Output seen from R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeG1b.png)

[Output seen from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EASrG.png)

My question is, how, in R, can I make those numbers become the date they are supposed to be? Especially since the class of the elements in those columns are characters.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could have a look at the readxl package, it's recently been overhauled. (https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl) There is a `col_types` argument to `read_excel()` that should help you out

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you are reading the file in your R code?

Comment: I use the command 
`DHL_obs <- read_excel(
  "~/Documents/Uni/Year 2/Skills II/file.xlsx")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates in your excel file are different formats. That is why some are to left side of column and some are to right side of column in the spreadsheet. They are probably mixed between an actual excel date format and a text or general. You should copy the columns to new columns and highlight the new column and right click and change format until all your dates are uniform. Then you can import to R and have consistent dates data.

Comment: Indeed, now in R it's even in the POSIXct format, which is even better than character! Thank you